# Angular recursive directive to represent tree structure needs adding file list

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive, tree

I have been attempting to update this directive to add fileList into the tree structure, but I was not successful. The original works fine (https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/JgQu3r), but it considers directories only. In my data structure any directory can have a `fileList`, as well as any number of nested `directoryList` and so on.

```js
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.menu = [{
      name: 'one',
      directoryList: [{
        name: 'one'
      }, {
        name: 'two'
      }],
      fileList: ['one.pdf', 'two.pdf', 'three.pdf']
    },
    {
      name: 'two',
      directoryList: [{
        name: 'one',
        directoryList: [{
          name: 'one'
        }],
        fileList: ['one.pdf', 'two.pdf', 'three.pdf', 'four.pdf']
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'three'
    }
  ];
}

function myMenu() {
  return {
    scope: {
      myMenu: '=myMenu'
    },
    template: '<li ng-repeat="item in myMenu"><my-menu-item></my-menu-item></li>',
    link: function(scope, elem) {}
  }
}

function myMenuItem($compile) {
  return {
    template: '<a href ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="show($event)"></a>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      if (angular.isArray(scope.item.menu)) {
        element.append($compile('<ul ng-if="collapsed" my-menu="item.menu"></ul>')(scope));

      }
      scope.show = function($event) {
        scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
      }
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .directive('myMenu', myMenu)
  .directive('myMenuItem', myMenuItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.14/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul my-menu="menu">
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish between files and folders. Just treat the folders like you treat it in your example, and treat your files separately. The following snippet works, but I recommend that you take a minute to think about why and how it works.

```js
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.menu = [{
      name: 'one',
      directoryList: [{
        name: 'one'
      }, {
        name: 'two'
      }],
      fileList: ['one.pdf', 'two.pdf', 'three.pdf']
    },
    {
      name: 'two',
      directoryList: [{
        name: 'one',
        directoryList: [{
          name: 'one'
        }],
        fileList: ['one.pdf', 'two.pdf', 'three.pdf', 'four.pdf']
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'three'
    }
  ];
}

function myMenu() {
  return {
    scope: {
      myMenu: '=myMenu'
    },
    template: '<li ng-repeat="item in myMenu"><my-menu-item></my-menu-item></li>',
    link: function(scope, elem) {}
  }
}

function myMenuItem($compile) {
  return {
    template: `
    <a href ng-bind="item.name" ng-click="show($event)"></a>
    `,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      if (angular.isArray(scope.item.directoryList)) {
        element.append($compile('<ul ng-if="!collapsed" my-menu="item.directoryList"></ul>')(scope));
      }

      if (angular.isArray(scope.item.fileList)) {
        element.append($compile(`
        <ul ng-if="item.fileList && !collapsed">
          <li ng-repeat="file in item.fileList">{{file}}</li>
        </ul>
        `)(scope));
      }
      scope.collapsed = true;
      scope.show = function($event) {
        scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
      }
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .directive('myMenu', myMenu)
  .directive('myMenuItem', myMenuItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.14/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul my-menu="menu">
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: "Treat your files separately" was the key point that I was missing. I was trying to nest the fileList part into the folders segment in the directive... Appreciate your help, all works now.